# Mudar máscara de um EditText em tempo de execução

Tags: android, edittext

Tenho um `EditText` que é usado para CPF e CNPJ. Preciso usá-lo hora como CNPJ e hora como CPF.

Preciso alterar a máscara em tempo de execução de acordo com o tipo selecionado (CNPJ/CPF), mas ao fazer isso, uma *exception* é gerada.

```
if(TipoPesso == FISICA){
  mEdtCGC.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert("###.###.###-##", mEdtCGC));
}else{
  mEdtCGC.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert("##.###.###/####-##", mEdtCGC));
}
```

Existe a possibilidade de utilizar dois tipos de máscara no mesmo `EditText`, alternando em tempo de execução?

Comment: Você pode [Edit] a pergunta e mostrar a exceção?

Comment: Nao pode mostrar ter 2 campos e mostrar só 1 deles na hora que precisa ?

Comment: Encontrei a solução do meu problema. https://andremrezende.wordpress.com/tag/android-mask-mascara-edittext-java-layout-cpf-cnpj/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;

public abstract class Mask {
    public static String CPF_MASK       = "###.###.###-##";
    public static String CELULAR_MASK   = "(##) #### #####";
    public static String CEP_MASK       = "#####-###";

    public static String unmask(String s) {
        return s.replaceAll("[.]", "").replaceAll("[-]", "")
                .replaceAll("[/]", "").replaceAll("[(]", "")
                .replaceAll("[)]", "").replaceAll(" ", "")
                .replaceAll(",", "");
    }

    public static boolean isASign(char c) {
        if (c == '.' || c == '-' || c == '/' || c == '(' || c == ')' || c == ',' || c == ' ') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static String mask(String mask, String text) {
        int i = 0;
        String mascara = "";
        for (char m : mask.toCharArray()) {
            if (m != '#') {
                mascara += m;
                continue;
            }
            try {
                mascara += text.charAt(i);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }

        return mascara;
    }

    public static TextWatcher insert(final String mask, final EditText ediTxt) {
        return new TextWatcher() {
            boolean isUpdating;
            String old = "";

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String str = Mask.unmask(s.toString());
                String mascara = "";
                if (isUpdating) {
                    old = str;
                    isUpdating = false;
                    return;
                }

                int index = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < mask.length(); i++) {
                    char m = mask.charAt(i);
                    if (m != '#') {
                        if (index == str.length() && str.length() < old.length()) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        mascara += m;
                        continue;
                    }

                    try {
                        mascara += str.charAt(index);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        break;
                    }

                    index++;
                }

                if (mascara.length() > 0) {
                    char last_char = mascara.charAt(mascara.length() - 1);
                    boolean hadSign = false;
                    while (isASign(last_char) && str.length() == old.length()) {
                        mascara = mascara.substring(0, mascara.length() - 1);
                        last_char = mascara.charAt(mascara.length() - 1);
                        hadSign = true;
                    }

                    if (mascara.length() > 0 && hadSign) {
                        mascara = mascara.substring(0, mascara.length() - 1);
                    }
                }

                isUpdating = true;
                ediTxt.setText(mascara);
                ediTxt.setSelection(mascara.length());
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        };
    }
}
```

Aí está o código da classe Mask. Com a diferença que ele vai funcionar também enquanto estiver deletando os characters. Levei quase 2 dias para implementar essa função adequadamente. Tá bem testada já.

Use essa classe assim:

```
EditedText etCPF = /* sua inicialização aqui */;
etCPF.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert(Mask.CPF_MASK, etCPF));
```

Se gostou da resposta marque-a como aceita!

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, eu aqui me matando, achando que quando estivesse apagando os dados, era algo em `afterTextChanged`. Me sinto ate mal de copiar e colar seu código kkk

Comment: @DanielBeltrami Que bom que te ajudou xD

Answer (score 5):

#### Solução

Importe o .java para seu projeto,  dê uma olhada [nessa class](https://github.com/jrvansuita/FormatacaoBR).

Você poderá utilizar deste jeito:

```
seuEditText.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert(Mask.MaskType.CNPJ,  seuEditText));

//Ou

seuEditText.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert(Mask.MaskType.CPF, seuEditText));
```